# connect python to wordpress database

Tags: database, wordpress, connection

I have wordpress running in the WEB catalog on my qnap, at the same time I have a python program running on my PC, the information that this program finds I would like to transfer to a database on the qnap, that is, if the database does not exist, it will be created by the program so that wordpress can access the new database and its information - how do you do it, for chatGPT is not of much help here

I have tried to connect the program via the ip address but cannot access the server, I use mariadb 10 together with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

WordPress itself depends on a MySQL / MariaDB database with [these table definitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

To transfer your data from your PC to make it accessible to WordPress, your best course of action is to place it on the same MySQL or MariaDB server that your WordPress instance uses. You can either put your data into tables of your own design, or you can figure out how to represent your data as WordPress posts, then transform it and load it directly into WordPress.

If you use your own tables you'll have to write a [WordPress plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to read their data and present it to WordPress users, possibly by creating a [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/) for the purpose.

If it makes sense to structure your data as WordPress posts, you may be able to load them into WordPress using its [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) rather than by transferring the tables from database to database. This is the path I would try to follow as it will result in a straighforward production workflow.